# MATLAB Parfor is running much slower on a 18-core PC than a 10-core PC

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am currently running a compute-intensive financial trading test; the test has 503 independent loops. I have two PCs in my office, one has 10-core Intel i9-10900k @ 3.7GHz with 128GB DDR4; the other one has 18-core Intel i9-7980XE @ 3.4GHz with 128GB DDR4 as well.

In order to speed up the whole processing, the first 10-core PC runs loop 1-to-189 in parfor; the second 18-core PC runs loop 190-to-503 in parfor.

After one-day running, I found the 10-core PC finished 25 loops, the 18-core PC only finished 4 loops. I found very curious, can anyone know the reason of this problem?

P.S. 10-core PC running MATLAB 2020b with latest updates with MOSEK 9.2.35
18-core PC running MATLAB 2021a with latest updates with MOSEK 9.2.36

I also checked the taskmgr.exe, unlike the 10-core PC, I found in 18-core PC, 10 matlab tasks are in one group, the other 10 tasks are seperated....

[image: 18-core PC taskmgr]

[image: 10-core PC taskmgr]

Comment: Without knowing more about the code, it's impossible for us to provide anything but guesswork. The PCs are different specs and running different MATLAB versions, the 10 core PC looks like it has a faster processor, the impact of those differences is likely not trivial. Perhaps your parallel loop is implemented with some broadcasting variables which then throttles processing based on the communication between nodes - we have literally no way of knowing

Comment: In addition to @Wolfie comment's, adding a parfor do not magically reduce the execution time, your code have to be parallelizable. If poorly implemented, a parfor could even be slower than a for loop due to overheads. So indeed we need more information and at the moment this question can not be answered.

Comment: Since you mention MOSEK: I don't know how heavily you use MOSEK in that, but you should probably specify with MSK_IPAR_NUM_THREADS that each instance should use only a few threads, possibly even 1 thread. Otherwise each of them tries to use all cores simultaneously and more time is wasted on switching than saved.

Comment: Thank you very much Michal!  You are absolutely correct, when I turn off the multi-threads in MOSEK, parfor-loop is now approx. 17 times faster than for-loop!

Comment: Note that, matlab workers are quite heaviweight, needing lots of ram (approx. Each worker at least 1gb). It could be that you run out of ram with 18 workers. If thats the case, you can try to use the new lightweight parpool, but not every matlab code can be executed in those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to Michal Adamaszek, When using the MOSEK (interior-point or integer programming) inside parfor loop, it is better to turn off the multi-threads in MOSEK, otherwise, by default, MOSEK will using all cores.

```
param.MSK_IPAR_NUM_THREADS = 1;
param.MSK_IPAR_INTPNT_MULTI_THREAD = 'MSK_OFF';
```